# JTextArea in MigLayout causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, miglayout, windowbuilder

I'm not a pro with swing layout managers and this behavior is completely baffling me.  Essentially I can't add a JTextArea or JTextPane to my MigLayout without getting a NullPointerException.

I created a class that extends JPanel:

```
public ComponentPanel(TestComponent testComponent) {
    setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[]", "[][][][][][]"));

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    add(lblNewLabel, "cell 0 0");

    JButton button = new JButton("New button");
    add(button, "cell 0 3");

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    add(btnNewButton, "cell 0 5");
}
```

This works fine.  However, if I try adding a textArea, it will throw an exception when I try to build:

```
public ComponentPanel(TestComponent testComponent) {
    setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow]", "[][grow][][][][]"));

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    add(lblNewLabel, "cell 0 0");

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    add(textArea, "cell 0 1,grow");

    JButton button = new JButton("New button");
    add(button, "cell 0 3");

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    add(btnNewButton, "cell 0 5");
}
```

I'm using the Window Designer in eclipse, so I'm assuming something is horking up the MigLayout constructor?  I've been beating my head on this for awhile and all I've managed to figure out is that adding textArea or textPanes causes the following exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   javax.swing.BoxLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.BorderLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)   at
>   net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout.adjustWindowSize(Unknown Source)   at
>   net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)    at
>   net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.BoxLayout.checkRequests(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.BoxLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Window.show(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.soartech.ssim.testbed.gui.TestbedApplication$1.run(TestbedApplication.java:25)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) Exception in thread
>   "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   javax.swing.SizeRequirements.calculateTiledPositions(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.swing.BoxLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: If you change the JTextArea to other components like button, label, etc., it works or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I needed to let SwingUtilities create my panels for me, because they were being programmatically generated.

```
    Runnable doWorkRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(TestComponent c : Config.getComponents()){
                frame.getContentPane().add(new ComponentPanel(c));
                frame.getContentPane().add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
            }
        }
    };
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doWorkRunnable);
```

Now that this is in place, I can include text areas in my MigLayout without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

With MigLayout 4.0 your code runs fine on my computer. If you fix your source attachment you might be able to dig down into `BoxLayout` and get a better idea about what is going on.

Without having the actual line number in the source, the only thing I see in `BoxLayout.preferredLayoutSize()` that might throw is if your UI is setting a `Border` that returns a null insets. This seems unlikely, but you could try setting a border on the text area explicitly just as an experiment.

Comment: I tried updating to MigLayout 4.0, but it didn't fix the problem.  I ended up tracking the problem further up the chain - I was building the display dynamically and needed to let SwingUtilities manage the creation of my panels.